# Как правильно вычислить цвет статусбара в зависисости от цвета Toolbar?

Tags: android, material-design, color, android-toolbar

Привет! Например я крашу `Toolbar` фиолетовым, а статусбар — цветом чуть потемнее. Мне кажется, это неправильно, наверняка есть формула для вычисления цвета статусбара чуть потемнее тулбара. Хочется тютелька в тютельку следовать за Material Design.

Comment: Обычно используют цвета на 1-2 тона темнее цвета тулбара. О формуле вычисления не слышал...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://apptractor.ru/info/news/google-vyipustil-instrument-dlya-podbora-tsvetov-materialnogo-dizayna.html) пишут что таки есть официальный инструмент для этого:

https://material.io/color/#!/

Там вы вводите/выбираете основной цвет и автоматически получаете его светлую/тёмную версию. Можно выбрать второй цвет с автоматически генерируемыми версиями и сразу увидеть как всё это будет выглядеть на разных макетах на девайсе. Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно если нужна формула, то её можно самостоятельно вычислить исходя из генерируемых сайтом цветов

Comment: Спасибо огромное :)

Answer (score 1):

> Хочется тютелька-в-тютельку следовать за материал дизайн

Примените один из 3 стилей:

```
@android:style/Theme.Material //темная версия
@android:style/Theme.Material.Light //светлая версия
@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar
```

Цвета смотрите в `R.style`

Comment: С ними статусбар будет сам краситься чуть потемнее `Toolbar`?